# Header Style Of Gridview not visible in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvScheduleHistory" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="false" > <HeaderStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="30px" CssClass="search" /> <RowStyle CssClass="gridview_row" /> <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BorderStyle="Solid" /> <Columns> <asp:BoundField DataField="EffectiveDate" HeaderText="Effective Date" ControlStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"
           Height="30px" CssClass="search" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

And this is css

```
.search
{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #f25d23;
}
```

Border of header is visible in all browser except IE

Help?

Comment: Do you have any other styles that impact this GridView? I don't see any border style defined.

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="gvScheduleHistory" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                ShowFooter="false" >
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    Height="30px" CssClass="search"  />
                <RowStyle CssClass="gridview_row" />
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BorderStyle="Solid" />
 <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="EffectiveDate" HeaderText="Effective Date" ControlStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-Width="20%" />

Comment: In many browser you have the possibility to inspect any html element. There you can see the applied CSS rules for any element.